# Is there a different term for "Casket lowering device"?

Tags: creative-writing, novel

I was writing something like:

*She stood in front of two open graves as the casket lowering devices slowly creaked in unison to what seemed like eternity.*

but it seems unnatural. Or out of place. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to writers!  Unfortunately this question belongs on a different stack exchange site (english) as they deal with the singular terms and words.

Comment: I think that English will close this unless you [demonstrate research effort](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed/5043#5043).

Comment: Welcome to Writers!  Questions asking for terms or rephrasing don't quite fit our scope.  They can fit on the English site, but as Neil said, you'd need to edit first.  Since you've accepted an answer, I've closed this here without migrating.  When you get a chance, you might want to check out our short [tour] to learn more about our site.  I hope to see you around.

Comment: I tried looking it up... and got "casket lowering device" as the first result.  https://www.frigidfluid.com/casket-lowering-devices/

Comment: If it were me, I wouldn't focus on the devices. "Creaking noises began in unison as the caskets slowly lowered into the ground."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cranks?

She stood in front of two open graves as cranks lowered the caskets, creaking in unison to what seemed like eternity.